# Tab hard to be clickable

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, mobile

I have a tab to be displayed on the bottom left corner of the window, but it seems to be hard to make it actually clickable (also the iframe is not clickable), so it does´t do any animation on cell phone and even web browser.

http://jsfiddle.net/bo9gy77q/3/

How could I fix this eror? In the console it says: `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined`. The problem with clicking the tab on mobile browsers, and make clickable the iframe?

Note: There is a iframe in the tab, so I also wil need it to be clickable, so far nothing that I tryed fix it.

Note: The hard to click is especially refered to old movile devices and safary.(so hard to make it work on those)

¿CAN I MAKE THE CLICKABLE ZONE BIGGER?

Comment: Your jquery code isn't inside a `ready()` block, so it could be executed before the DOM is fully loaded, or before the jQuery library was loaded. The error you're getting suggests the latter. http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: Have you noticed that your fiddle is not including jquery? That´s the reason to have the $ is not defined...

Comment: Check your fiddle I've added some minor edits: http://jsfiddle.net/bo9gy77q/1/

Comment: only in the jsfiddle is not including a jquery. The problem is no when it is excecuted, but that might fix other problems with it thanks.

Comment: I didn't knew how to add jquery to the jsfiddle thanks.

Comment: I added the iframe (I found how to do it) so now you will see the problem I have and the thing that I can't do. I just always wanted to know how to make the iframe clickable too, but `#a-tab *` doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at this fiddle, animation is working now fine and smooth : http://jsfiddle.net/bo9gy77q/2/
I have just removed transition property from "#a-tab" class and smoothness is there

```js
$("#a-tab,#a-tab *").click(function () {
    //$("#a-tab").focus();
    $("#a-tab").animate({
        width: '320px'
    }, "fast");
    $(".deluxe").animate({
        width: '30px'
    }, "slow");
})
$("#a-tab").on('focusout', function () {
    $("#a-tab").animate({
        width: '10px'
    }, "fast");
    $(".deluxe").animate({
        width: '5px'
    }, "fast");
});
```

```css
#a-tab:focus {
    outline:none;
    width:340px;
}
.deluxe {
    position: relative;
    background:#999;
    width:5px;
    height:108px;
}
#a-tab {
    background:#FFF;
    border:solid #d9d9d9 2px;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 12px;
    right: -20px;
    z-index: 5;
    width: 30px;
    height: 112px;
    padding: 5px 20px 5px 5px;
    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="a-tab" tabindex="1">
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div class="deluxe"></div>
                </td>
                <td></td>
                <td>
                    <div class="g-page" data-width="273" data-href="//plus.google.com/u/0/111125806825828710565" data-layout="landscape" data-rel="publisher"></div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks it helps to the tab, but I recently discovered how to add the iframe wich is the main problem. please could you look at it and help me?

Comment: you can ask this as seperate question, but for current question if your problem gets solved than please upvote answer